# Reading csv and importing into datatable (Python)

Tags: python, python-3.4

New to python,so im reading an excel csv and i want to import the results into a datatable for use in later code, i.e i want to reference column names in logic to generate results.

below is my code thus far, the excel reading bit is fine, i left that there to work on, but i cant get datatables to work i think im missing something simple

I have got easy install in and have setup tools on, i have the webpaste kit installed but i cant reference it. i also just run `datatables-0.4.9/setup.py` aswell but am not sure how i need to reference this in my script to begin working on it.

```
import csv
import datatables
with open('Data/ShowroomData.csv', 'rt') as Data:
    SR = csv.reader(Data, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    next(Data)
    for row in SR:
        print (row)

table = DataTable('Data/ShowroomData.csv', 'rt')
for row in table:
        print (row['SiteName'], row['BGPAS'])
```

Comment: Do I understand you correctly: You want to read a CSV file and be able to access different fields of a row using its column name from the header?

Comment: Your code has some issuses: 1) You don't import `DataTable`. 2) The indention of your last line is broken. 3) Rename `Data` to `data` and `SR` to `sr`. 4) Use `print(row)` instead of `print (row)`.

Comment: @L3viathan yes this is correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to be able to access the attributes of each row by the column name, I  don't think you need [`datatables`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/datatables/0.4.9). All you need is a [`DictReader` from the `csv` standard library module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader).

The code would look something like this:

```
import csv
with open('Data/ShowroomData.csv', 'rt') as Data:
    SR = csv.DictReader(Data, delimiter=' ', quotechar='|')
    for row in SR:
        # if you were to print just `row`, you would get a dictionary
        # like {'SiteName': 'foo', 'BGPAS': 'bar'}
        print (row['SiteName'], row['BGPAS'])
```

Comment: I key a KeyError SiteName, do i need to tell the reader that the first row is column headers?

Comment: No, `DictReader` automatically treats the first row as the column headers.

Comment: It's hard to tell. Can you post your updated code and a sample (just the first few rows) of your csv?

Comment: figured it out, my csv used , as a delimeter, your code above now works Thanks

Comment: Cool, glad you got it figured out!